# jquery to display actual picture

Tags: jquery

This jQuery should give me thumbnail view of the icjpg.gif but it does not give the actual image that are in the document library. Any idea what I am doing wrong? It just gives me the sharepoint icjpg.gif in bigger size. It's supposed to be working. http://sharepointblog.kellerschroeder.com/2009/05/using-jquery-to-display-image.html
[image]

```
<SCRIPT defer type=text/javascript> 
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$("img[src$='icjpg.gif']").each(SetImage); 

}); 
function SetImage() 
{ 

$(this).attr('height','100'); 
$(this).attr('src',$(this).parent().attr('href')); 

} 
</SCRIPT>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a problem locating the parent href attribute. I did notice that the object itself has a title attribute. So here is a workaround:

```
<SCRIPT defer type=text/javascript>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("img[src$='icjpg.gif']").each(SetImage);

});
function SetImage()
{
    $(this).attr('height','100');
    $(this).attr('src','/<<your document library name>>/'+$(this).attr('title'));
    // try this code
    //$(this).attr('src','/managedpath/sitename/library/'+$(this).attr('title')); 
}
</SCRIPT>
```

Also just wondering why you could not just use a picture library and get all the preview options inbuilt?

Comment: I can't use picture library as this library is the place for all types of documents. I created a view for pictures only. The code you provided does the same thing with my originally posted code. Any other ideas?

Comment: Are you sure? The code I posted above I have tested on my site. Can you post the setImage() function code as you have modified it for your library?  This is how it looks for me:    $(this).attr('src','/test/'+$(this).attr('title'));  Here test is the name of my document library

Comment: I have posted the picture with my original post on how it looks like. Here is my non working code $(this).attr('src','/InfrastructureDocuments/'+$(this).attr('title'));

Comment: $(this).attr('src','/managedpath/sitename/library/'+$(this).attr('title')); this worked. Thanks Ransher for your valuable support. I truly appreciate it. Thanks Eric for pitching in and help us out.

Answer (score 2):

Ah, it is working, but the URL to the picture is malformed, hence the x images. This is what worked for me:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("img[src$='icjpg.gif']").each(SetImage);

});
function SetImage()
{
    $(this).attr('height','100');
    $(this).attr('src','/managedpath/sitename/library/'+$(this).attr('title'));
}
</script>
```